# _id is not getting autogenerated in Elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, nest

I have a simple list of documents of type SalesOrder. While inserting them to elastic search, _id is taking the value of SalesOrderId. I need it to be autogenerated. Below is my class

```
    public class SalesOrder
    {
        [XmlElement("Id")]
        public long SalesOrderId { get; set; }

        public long CustomerId { get; set; }

        public DateTime? BookedDate { get; set; }

        public long SalesOrderNo { get; set; }
     }
```

This is how i am inserting the docs in elastic search

```
            ElasticClient elasticClient = CreateElasticClient(indexName);

            if (!elasticClient.IndexExists(i => i.Index(indexName)).Exists)
            {
                elasticClient.CreateIndex(indexName, s => s.AddMapping<T>(m => m
                .MapFromAttributes()));
            }

            // create indexes
            var response = elasticClient.IndexMany<T>(documents);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can specify an Id field for ES to use like this:

```
[ElasticType(Name = "salesOrder", IdProperty = "Id")]
public class SalesOrder
{        
    public string Id {get;set;}//this is used internally by ES

    public long SalesOrderId { get; set; }

    public long CustomerId { get; set; }

    public DateTime? BookedDate { get; set; }

    public long SalesOrderNo { get; set; }
 }
```

Note: If you populate Id it will use that value to insert into ES.  If you leave it null then ES will create it automatically for you.

Also, if your SalesOrder class is specific to ElasticSearch then it should not have an XmlElement tag on it.

Comment: @jhilden- i am using the same class to deserialize the xml. would there be any problem because of that in case of elastic search?

Comment: Add in the [ElasticType] attribute and try it with the XML stuff in there. It will probably work. That being said, if you're working on an enterprise level system it is good practice to have separate models for each.